# django and condition in ifequal statement throws error

Tags: django, django-templates

I  need to display a portion of HTML on the following condition,

var1=="google" and var2 is True

I wrote the following code ,

```
{% ifequal var1 "google" and var2 %}
      /*HTML CODE */
{% endif %}
```

and i got an error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /process/apply.html
u'ifequal' takes two arguments
```

I know i can split the above two nested IF statements,still  is there a way in django  to combine them to a single if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [django ifequal documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal)

*It is only possible to compare an argument to template variables or strings. You cannot check for equality with Python objects such as True or False. If you need to test if something is true or false, use the if tag instead.*

So if you want to check for `True` or `False`, so need to use `if`.

```
{%if var1 == "google" and var2 %}
....
{%endif%}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'template tags' in this context?